# how to sort linked list and get input 2 line just number (output do not same number)

Tags: python

I trying to do like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63312.png)

```
        a = input()
        b = input()
        c = a+b
        for a in b:
               if a not in b:
                  b.append(a)
        sorted(c)
```

Comment: Please explain what you are actually trying to do here. Do u want to mix these two strings  but not take the repeated values?

Comment: @BearChef Feel free to accept an answer if you found it helpful. Click on the grey checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: SiddharthAgrawal I don't know how to repeated values.
Justin I'm sorry, my apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = input("Input L1 -")
b = input("Input L2 -")
c = ""
for x in a:#Looping through the first string letter by letter
   if x not in b and x not in c: #if the letter has not already been added or is not in the other string, we add it to the final string
      c += x
for x in b:#Now we loop the second string
   if x not in c:#If the letter has not already been added, we add it
      c += x
c = ''.join(sorted(c)) #Sorting it by order

print ("Output: ",c)
```

Comment: Oh you need some points to upvote yeahh. But the owner can accept the answer so please do that

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/9193372) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: While I totally understand your point Syscall, the requested answer was for a code snippet and I have explained throughout the code using comments how it functions

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`set()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-set-method/) function -

```
a = [2,3,4,6,8,9]
b = [1,2,2,6,8]
new_list = list(set(a + b))
print (new_list)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9]
```